# FullCalendar Event Source Error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: rawEvents is not iterable

Tags: json, fullcalendar

I use PHP to generate JSON and receive the error in my console when loading FullCalendar and using the eventSources option to point at the PHP script. The JSON sent is verified by JSONLint as follows:

```
{"events": [{"id":"1","title":"First Event","start":"2023-11-30","end":"2023-12-08","editable":false,"backgroundColor":"#FFFFAA","textColor":"#000000"}]}
```

Can anyone spot the error, please?

Answer (score 2):

If I simply removed `{"events":`  from the beginning and the final `}`, it all started working!

Comment: Correct. That's because fullCalendar requires that you provide it with a simple array of events, whereas your original version was an object which then contained an array within a property of that object. FullCalendar isn't equipped to be able to read the events from within that - it can only cope with the array on its own.